# Automatically overlay a transparent gif over real images inside the Fancybox frame

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I found this jQuery solution to automatically overlay a transparent gif over real images.

http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/stop-the-thieves-strategies-to-protect-your-images/

("Tricking the Downloaders")

It works fine on my Wordpress site (v. 3.5.1) with FancyBox plug-in (v. 1.3.4).

**But now all my links related to images are gone...**

Is there any solution to keep active links related to images?

I have also tried to attribute the overlay gif only to images inside the fancybox frame, but without success...

**>>EDIT POSTING RELEVANT CODE<<**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var pixelSource = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif';
    var useOnAllImages = true;
    // Preload the pixel
    var preload = new Image();
    preload.src = pixelSource;
    $('img').live('mouseenter touchstart', function(e) {
        // Only execute if this is not an overlay or skipped
        var img = $(this);
        if (img.hasClass('protectionOverlay')) return;
        if (!useOnAllImages && !img.hasClass('protectMe')) return;
        // Get the real image's position, add an overlay
        var pos = img.offset();
        var overlay = $('<img class="protectionOverlay" src="' + pixelSource + '" width="' + img.width() + '" height="' + img.height() + '" />').css({position: 'absolute', zIndex: 9999999, left: pos.left, top: pos.top}).appendTo('body').bind('mouseleave', function() {
            setTimeout(function(){ overlay.remove(); }, 0, $(this));
        });
        if ('ontouchstart' in window) $(document).one('touchend', function(){ setTimeout(function(){ overlay.remove(); }, 0, overlay); });
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks and sorry for my poor english.
d.

Comment: You could try to deter potential thieves but unfortunately there is not real protection with javascript (I can download any image from your site no matter how hard you try to trick me.) Your best best is to find a server side solution that adds watermark to your images on the fly if you don't want to add the watermark manually. Potential thieves still will be able to download your watermarked images.

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.4 for code examples of adding watermark and disabling the right click, if that helps to your peace of mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is placing a watermark on your images an option?
When you place a gif over an image you can block the save image with right mouse button.
But with Firefox you can right click anywhere and choose 'view page info' then the tab media from there you can still download the image.

PS:
Or someone with JS disabled can also download the image.

Comment: Hi, I thank you for the answer.

I want to add a transparent layer to my image in order to prevent downloading (I am aware of the rather low level of security).

I would also avoid the solution with the watermark for purely aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  {just be aware that any javascript protection are useless for experienced developpers}

```
$(function() {
    var pixelSource = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif';
    var useOnAllImages = true;
    // Preload the pixel
    var preload = new Image();
    preload.src = pixelSource;
    //live is deprecated, use 'on' instead
    $(document).on('mouseenter touchstart','img', function(e) {
        // Only execute if this is not an overlay or skipped
        var img = $(this);
        if (img.hasClass('protectionOverlay')) return;
        if (!useOnAllImages && !img.hasClass('protectMe')) return;
        // Get the real image's position, add an overlay
        var pos = img.offset();
        var overlay = $('<img class="protectionOverlay" src="' + pixelSource + '" width="' + img.width() + '" height="' + img.height() + '" />').css({position: 'absolute', zIndex: 9999999, left: pos.left, top: pos.top}).appendTo('body').bind('mouseleave', function() {
            setTimeout(function(){ overlay.remove(); }, 0, $(this));
        }).click(function(){
           if(img.parent('a').length)//assuming your image is embeded in a link tag
              window.location.replace(img.parent('a').attr('href'));
        });
        if ('ontouchstart' in window) $(document).one('touchend', function(){ setTimeout(function(){ overlay.remove(); }, 0, overlay); });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi roasted. I thank you for your kindly help.

Unfortunately, the version that you proposed seems to work exactly as the original: the links related to images remain inactive ...

Comment: You should post html code of your images, i mean how do you set link to images?

Comment: I the traditional way : <a href="full-image.jpg"><img src="thumbnail-image.jpg"/></a>

Comment: Thank you very very much, but it still does not work... Maybe you know an alternative solution where the transparent image (gif) is added only to the framed fancybox full-image? In this way we avoid the problem of the related link...

Comment: EDIT: sorry, it actually works but partially. Let me explain: the cursor does not change state (remains an arrow), but if I click on the image I am immediately directed to the full-image, but outside the Fancybox frame and without the transparent protection...

Comment: Could you post link to your website or better create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi roasted, sorry for the late reply. Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U8jSd/2/